# inserts in ClickHouse database

Tags: database, clickhouse

currently I'm using ClickHouse database and I have some trouble in inserting data to database. Question: how to insert data from file(insert script) in ClickHouse database

Comment: I literally pasted your question into google and got this: https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/external_data/
i hope it helps. If not you can always tell us what you've tried in your post.

Comment: @SebastianL thank you,  I will try

Answer (score 4):

With `clickhouse-client`:

```
cat data.csv | clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO data FORMAT CSV";
```

Or via http interface

```
cat data.csv | curl http://localhost:8123/?query=INSERT%20INTO%20default.data%20FORMAT%20CSV' --data-binary @-
```

For the POST requests, you can pass your data directly in request body which is more suitable for large datasets.